# If $u^2 = 2x-1$, why does $du^2 = dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

So the problem i encountered was:

$$\int_1^5\frac{x}{\sqrt {2x-1}}dx$$

the first step in the given solution was:

$$u^2 = 2x-1  \Rightarrow 2du^2 = 2dx \Rightarrow udu ~\text{(or} ~ du^2\text{)} = dx,$$

which confused me, as the derivative of $u^2$ in this situation should be $2 dx$.

Comment: Seems like a typo to me, the "2du^2" should be just du^2.

Comment: Tiny recommendation: it's a really good idea to write $d(u^2)$ in circumstances like this so it's not confused with $(du)^2$ (which is a depressingly easy mistake to make in this sort of problem).

Comment: @Wojowu 

not a typo.

Comment: @Axe I meant the provided solution has a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\textrm{d}u^2 = 2u\ \textrm{d}u \\ \textrm{d}(2x-1) = 2\ \textrm{d}x$$ Because $u^2=2x-1$, we know that $\textrm{d}u^2 = \textrm{d}(2x-1)$ as well.  And thus $2u\ \textrm{d}u = 2\ \textrm{d}x$, or cancelling the $2$'s: $$u\ \textrm{d}u = \textrm{d}x$$

If your solution sheet says anything else, it must be a typo as Wojowu says in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_1^5\frac{x}{\sqrt {2x-1}}dx$

$u^2 = 2x -1\\
x = \frac 12(u^2 + 1)\\
dx = u\ du\\$

$\int_1^3 \frac 12 (u^2+1) du$